# `ls` in Singularity container shows different content based on path

Tags: binding, mount, singularity-container

This is best elucidated with an example.
I have the following directory structure:

```
my_home
├── dir1
│   ├── dir2.1
│   │   └── dir3
│   ├── dir2.2
```

I launch Singularity shell from `dir3` using:
`singularity shell --no-home --cleanenv -B /dir1 ~/image.sif`

Now, inside the shell if I run `ls ../..` or `ls /[absolute path]/my_home`, it will print out `dir2.1`.

But if I run `ls ~/dir1` it will print `dir2.1   dir2.2`.

`../..`, `/[absolute path]/my_home`, and `~/dir1` all point to the same directory. Why is `dir2.2` invisible to `ls ../..` and `ls /[absolute path]/my_home`?

Additional info: If I eliminate the `--no-home` flag, `dir2.2` will be invisible to all three of `ls` commands.

Answer (score 1):

*General answer:*

The directory structure inside a singularity container is combination of the image and directories that were bound/mounted either implicitly or explicitly. The output may not be as you expect in certain cases if you rely only on the implicit binds.

When run, Singularity determines the in-container working directory by picking the first existing directory in the following order/hierarchy:

1. `$PWD`
2. `$HOME`
3. `/`

The key here is `existing directory`. Both `$PWD` and `$HOME` are directories that are [automatically added to the bind list by default](https://docs.sylabs.io/guides/3.10/user-guide/bind_paths_and_mounts.html#system-defined-bind-paths). There is an important caveat: the implicit `$PWD` bind will fail if the parent directory path does not exist in the image. Adding any explicit bind with that root directory will allow the implicit bind to work as expected. There are also flags that can be used to change what is automatically bound to a container.

```bash
# location on host OS
pwd
# /opt/singularity

# /opt/singularity directory does not exist in the alpine:latest image
singularity exec -e ./alpine_latest.sif pwd
# /home/tsnowlan

# just /opt does though
cd /opt
singularity exec -e ./alpine_latest.sif pwd
# /opt

# return to path that doesn't exist in the image
cd /opt/singularity
# using --no-home stops $HOME from being implicitly bound
singularity exec --no-home -e ./alpine_latest.sif pwd
# /

# explicitly bind parent directory /opt
singularity exec -B /opt --no-home -e ./alpine_latest.sif pwd
# /opt/singularity

# explicitly bind sibling directory
singularity exec -B /opt/docker --no-home -e pwd
# /

# explicitly bind $PWD
singularity exec -B $PWD --no-home -e ./alpine_latest.sif pwd
# /opt/singularity

# --no-home just stops $HOME from being _automatically_ bound, explicit still works
singularity exec -B $HOME --no-home -e ./alpine_latest.sif pwd
# /home/tsnowlan
```

---

*Specific example*

Your confusion is understandable, as that should not be something that happens. I am also not able to replicate the issue, so there may be a sneaky typo or environmental problem. Try the following and see if that helps you sort it out.

```bash
pwd
# /home/tsnowlan/dir1/dir2.1/dir3

singularity exec --no-home --cleanenv -B ~/dir1 ~/image.sif pwd
# /home/tsnowlan/dir1/dir2.1/dir3

singularity exec --no-home --cleanenv -B ~/dir1 ~/image.sif ls -1 ../..
# dir2.1
# dir2.2

singularity exec --no-home --cleanenv -B ~/dir1 ~/image.sif ls -1 /home/tsnowlan
# dir1
singularity exec --no-home --cleanenv -B ~/dir1 ~/image.sif ls -1 ~
# dir1

singularity exec --no-home --cleanenv -B ~/dir1 ~/image.sif ls -1 ~/dir1
# dir2.1
# dir2.2
singularity exec --no-home --cleanenv -B ~/dir1 ~/image.sif ls -1 /home/tsnowlan/dir1
# dir2.1
# dir2.2

ls -1d ~/dir1/**/*
# /home/tsnowlan/dir1/dir2.1
# /home/tsnowlan/dir1/dir2.1/dir3
# /home/tsnowlan/dir1/dir2.2

singularity exec --no-home --cleanenv -B ~/dir1 ~/image.sif ls -1d ~/dir1/**/*
# /home/tsnowlan/dir1/dir2.1
# /home/tsnowlan/dir1/dir2.1/dir3
# /home/tsnowlan/dir1/dir2.2
```